# Drupal 7 Service Rest api

Tags: php, json, rest, drupal

> ```
>    For  a {node} when i am using "GET" for details this is the result
> ```

```
 "field_attachment_file": {
        "und": [
            {
                "fid": "73",             
                "filename": "Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20.png",
                "uri": "public://Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20_2.png",
                "filemime": "image/png",                   
                "status": "1",             
                "type": "undefined",

            },

        ]
    }
```

**here above "fid" is some how added when i am uploading through form but
 when iam uploading through json data i just incremented the "fid" to
 "74"
when  iam inserting through json in postman for the same node**

```
 "field_attachment_file": {
        "und": [
            {
                "fid": "74",
                "uid": "1",
                "filename": "Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20.png",
                "uri": "http://webiste/api/v1/file/66",
                "filemime": "image/png",
                "status": "1",
                "type": "undefined"
            }


        ]
    }
```

> I want to set the "fid" for uploading multiple images for a single nid

**This is the result i am getting**
[image]

**The field is multiupload**[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First hit site/access point/file and post the file**

```
"fid": "73",
    "uid": "1",
    "filename": "Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20 (6th copy).png",
    "uri": "public://Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20 (6th copy).png",
    "filemime": "image/png",
    "filesize": "159999",
    "status": "1",
    "timestamp": "1528444702",
    "type": "undefined",
    "rdf_mapping": [],
    "metadata": [],
    "uri_full": "http://webiste/sites/default/files/Screenshot%20from%202018-06-08%2012-54-20%20%286th%20copy%29.png",
    "target_uri": "Screenshot from 2018-06-08 12-54-20 (6th copy).png",
    "file": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABkAAA
```

**then you will get fid .use the fid to upload it to node**